# python return None if dict doesn't have key or is value is empty

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to return `None` if a dictionary `x` doesn't have the key `field` or if it does have the key but the value is an empty dict.

I had `results = x.get('field')` which returns `None` if the key isn't present. If it is present `x.get('field')` will return an dict. I want `results` to also be `None` if `x.get('field')` returns `{}`. Is there a nice pythonic way of doing this?

Currently I have `results = x.get('field') if x.get('field') else None`. This seems very convoluted.

Comment: I would probably write this as an explicit conditional so it's a little more obvious what I'm testing for. `results = x.get('field'); if not results: results = None`

Comment: What you currently have works perfectly, and is probably how I would implement it since it takes only one line. @AdamSmith's suggestion also works, but is essentially the same piece of code but easier to read for Python novices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `or` operator to explicitly return `None` if the dict contains a empty dict

```
results = x.get('field') or None
```

But be aware that you would get None, for other types of values whole bool status is false, for example `0`, `''` etc.

Comment: is it necessary to specify the default type `None` for `get()`? I thought would default to `None`

Comment: @mysticalstick it is not, `d.get("missing_key")` will default to `None` with or without the second argument explicitly as `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Python is duck typed, and a dictionary can contain any kind of value. You would have to explicitly check if the return value is a dict and whether it's empty.

```
value = x.get('field')
if value == {}:
    value = None
```